# Pandas: how to filter out rows containing a string pattern within a list in a column?

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame that looks similar to the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'employee_id' : [123, 456, 789],
    'country_code' : ['US', 'CAN', 'MEX'],
    'comments' : (['good performer', 'due for raise', 'should be promoted'],
                 ['bad performer', 'should be fired', 'speak to HR'],
                 ['recently hired', 'needs training', 'shows promise'])
})

df

    employee_id   country_code   comments
0   123           US             [good performer, due for raise, should be promoted]
1   456           CAN            [bad performer, should be fired, speak to HR]
2   789           MEX            [recently hired, needs training, shows promise]
```

I would like to be able to filter the `comments` column to ***remove any rows*** containing the string 'performer'.  To do so, I'm using:

```
df = df[~df['comments'].str.contains('performer')]
```

But, this returns an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give!

Answer (score 1):

if IIUC You need to break the comments column down into a string instead of a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'employee_id' : [123, 456, 789],
    'country_code' : ['US', 'CAN', 'MEX'],
    'comments' : (['good performer', 'due for raise', 'should be promoted'],
                 ['bad performer', 'should be fired', 'speak to HR'],
                 ['recently hired', 'needs training', 'shows promise'])
})
df['comments'] = df['comments'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
df = df[~df['comments'].str.contains('performer')]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have lists in your Series, you cannot vectorize. You can use a list comprehension:

```
df2 = df[[all('performer' not in x for x in l)
          for l in df['comments']]]
```

Output:

```
   employee_id country_code                                         comments
2          789          MEX  [recently hired, needs training, shows promise]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[~df['comments'].map(' '.join).str.contains('performer')]
```